# Strip html tags in preprocess hook

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

We have a `mytheme.theme` file that has a `mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables)` function. Within this preprocess hook, we would like to remove all HTML tags within a formatted (long) field. The goal is to do without using `striptags` within the `node--page.html.twig` template.

**How can we do this securely without using `striptags` in a `twig` template?**

Here is what we tried, but cannot find how to do it using `mytheme_preprocess_node` hook.

`mytheme.theme`

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $node = $variables['node'];
  $field_value = $node->get('body')->first()->getValue()['value'];
  ksm($field_value);
  // cannot find way to remove `html` tags

  $variables['field_value'] = $field_value;
}
```

node--page.html.twig

```
{{ field_value }}
```

output of `ksm($field_value)`

```
"& lt;p & gt;When looking at & lt;a href=&quot;https://www.example.com/some-path/&quot;& gt;article trends& lt;/a& gt; over time, attacks are cyclical in nature. Attackers develop new attack types and vectors, which are used to launch a new wave of attacks. As defenders become more proficient in stopping these new attacks, the attackers develop new types of attacks and the cycle repeats itself.&lt;/p& gt;
```

In order to properly display the output, I had to a space between `&` and `lt` characters above because StackExchange will convert those to proper tags. Within the `ksm` statement there is no space.

Additional item we tried within a twig template, but not sure if it is secure.

```
{% set body_processed = {
  '#type' : 'processed_text',
  '#text' : content.body.0,
  '#format' : content.body.format
} %}
```

Comment: You could use strip_tags() in PHP like in Twig, there is no difference, but this is not safe. You need to process the text format with the text filters now configured for the input data and add an additional one for removing the tags.

Comment: @4k4 only other option is to do `{{ field_value|render|striptags }}` in the `twig` templates, but i found that `striptags` is also not safe

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to output the field rendered normally in a safe way?

Comment: @4k4 Yes because we want to use the output in snippets such as ones in the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56263449/multiple-faqpage-featured-snippet-on-a-single-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then better apply [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on the processed text `$node->body->processed`. You might also want to apply [Html::decodeEntities()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AdecodeEntities/8.7.x). Still take care you configure the text format restrictively, because outputting the text in a non standard way can be a security risk increasing with features you allow. And you don't get security updates for custom code.